# What is called Base in Dojo?

Tags: dojo

> The kernel of Dojo is Base, an ultra-compact, highly optimized library
>   that provides the foundation for everything else in the toolkit.

I'm quite new to dojo toolkit and confused in the above context of ***kernal of dojo***  as whether they are meaning dojo.js file or all the file inside the dojo directory?

Can some explain me what is really called Base in Dojo?

Comment: A link to that quote would be useful.

Comment: I don't know where you found that quote, but you can see the details here : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/index.html#dojo-index

Answer (score 0):

dojo/_base is a subset of the dojo package.

At this point, it exists mostly for legacy reasons, but it was originally created as a list of what was included in the built version of dojo.js by default.

The idea was to create the same version of dojo.js, and for CDNs, without immediately needing to load additional resources.

With the emergence of AMD, _base has outlived its usefulness and is a legacy thing that will go away with Dojo 2.